# obtainStyleAttributes() ignores certain attributes I am trying to retrieve

Tags: android, attributes, android-theme, android-styles

I am trying to retrieve a set of style attributes using obtainStyleAttributes(), but I am only getting the first few items retrieved, while all the others get defaulted.  I confirmed that my style contains a non-default value for those attributes.  Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I wasted 3 hours on this issue, so I hope this will save somebody some time.

public TypedArray obtainStyledAttributes (AttributeSet set, int[] attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
The second argument attrs MUST contain the attribute identifiers in a strictly increasing numeric order, otherwise the attribute value won't get resolved and the call will silently fail as if the attribute did not exist.

This is no where documented that I can see and it took me forever to figure out what was going wrong.

So let's say I have 2 attributues, ATTR1 with ID = 1 and ATTR2 with ID = 2 (in real life these numbers are much larger and are assigned by the resource compiler).

If I want to retrieve the values of both attributes in one call, I must write:

int[] attributes = { ATTR1, ATTR2 };

If instead, I would swap them, only ATTR2 would be retrieved, and ATTR1 would be default instead.